# Metric space is discrete iff each of the points are isolated.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Forward direction is easy

Assume that $(X, d)$ is discrete.
Then $d(x, y)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{, if } x=y \\ 1 & \text{, if } x \neq y \end{cases}$

Then $\forall x\in X:$ Choose $\varepsilon = 0.5$. $B(x, \varepsilon)=\{ x \}$ in metric $d$.

Anyone can help me the proof of backward? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between '$X$ is a discrete metric space' and '$X$ is a metric space with the discrete metric'.

The first one simply means that every subset is open (equivalently, every singleton set is open). Note that in  $\mathbb N$ with the usual metric every point is isolated but this space does not have the discrete metric: $d(1,3)=2$, for example.

If each point is isolated then, for each $x$,  there is a ball $B(x,r)$ around $x$ which contains no other point, so $\{x\}=B(x,r)$ is open.

Conversely, if each  singleton subset is open then each point is isolated because $\{x\}$ is itself an open set containing $x$ which contains no other point.